# object dimensions in image according to camera distance faraway

Tags: image, math, image-processing, geometry, space

I have a camera placed 10 meters faraway from a portrait (rectangle) having width = 50cm and height = 15cm, I want to get the dimensions of this portrait inside the image captured. The image captured has width=800 px and height=600 px.

How can I calculate the dimensions of the portrait inside the image? Any help please?

Comment: You need to specify the field of view of the camera (i.e., the camera model).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the camera is located along the center normal of the portrait, looking straight at the portrait's center.

Let's define some variables.

- Horizontal field of view: FOV (you need to specify)
- Physical portrait width: PW = 50 cm
- Width of portrait plane captured: CW cm (unknown)
- Image width: IW = 800 px
- Width of portrait in image space: X px (unknown)
- Distance from camera to subject: D = 10 m

We know tan(FOV) = (CW cm) / (100 * D cm). Therefore CW = tan(FOV) * 100 * D cm.

We know PW / CW = X / IW. Therefore X = (IW * PW) / (tan(FOV) * 100 * D) px.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want some clarifications about what do you mean by Horizontal field of view ? And what is the difference between Width of portrait plane captured and Width of portrait in image space ?

Comment: @0_0 The horizontal field of view is the extent to which the camera can see to either side. For example, a 90 degree horizontal field of view means that the camera can see straight ahead and 45 degrees to either side. Width of portrait in image space is how wide (in pixels) the portrait appears in your camera's image.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Timothy's answer, in that you need to the know the camera's field of view (FOV). I'm not sure I totally follow/agree with his method however. I think this is similar, but it differs, the FOV needs to be divided by two to split our view into two right-angled triangles. Use tan(x)=opposite/adjacent

tan(FOV/2) = (IW/2) / (Dist * 100)

where *IW* is the true image width (must divide by two as we are only finding finding half of the width with the right-angled triangle), *Dist* is the distance from the camera to the portrait (converted to cm).

Rearrange that to find the Width of the entire image (IW):

IW = tand(FOV/2) * (2*Dist*100)

You can now work out the width of each pixel (PW) using the number of pixels in the image width (800 for you).

PW = IW / NumPixels
PW = IW / 800

Now divide the true width by this value to find the number of pixels.

PixelWidth = TrueWidth / PW

The same can be done for the height, but you need your camera's field of view.
Im not sure this is the same a Timothy's answer, but I'm pretty sure this is correct.